# get Application pool version from IIS6-IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, iis-6

Hello i want to get framework version from all my application pool (with IIS 6/7).
This is how i get application pool name:

```
Dim AppPools As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools")Then
     For Each nextEntry As DirectoryEntry In AppPools.Children
            Dim nextAppPoolName As String = nextEntry.Name
            Dim pipelineMode As Integer = CInt(nextApplicationPool.Properties(MANAGED_PIPELINE_MODE).Value)                  
     Next
```

i can get framework from my web sites but i don't want this.
how i can to do?

Answer (score 0):

We use IIS-api for IIS7:

```
using (var iisManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(iisServer))
{
    var site = iisManager.Sites[IisSite];
    var app = site.Applications[0];

    var pool = iisManager.ApplicationPools[app.ApplicationPoolName];
}
```

Where `iisServer` is name of your server (localhost), `IisSite` - name of site on server, `app` - first (default) apllication of this site and `pool` - your apllication pool.

More information about [pool api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool(v=vs.90).aspx) and [ServerManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx). I hope, you can translate it to VB.

IIS6 has no api and almost has any "good" way to get this information.

Comment: i can have an application pool with no sites and i can't get this info.

Comment: @fabio `iisManager.ApplicationPools` - is a collection, you can iterate through it

Comment: @fabio very sad :( i'll research more

Comment: @fabio look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149724/iis6-list-the-version-of-net-an-application-pool-is-running as it says, there is no "good" solution

Comment: he select all sites and get it .net version but if i have an application pool with no sites i can't have any information right?

Comment: @fabio looks so. IIS6 has no functions to get this information